# bash shell scripting error

Tags: command-line, scripts

I thought there is no syntax for `echo` keyword i.e we can use `"` or `'` or no quotes.

I tried all three types in bash shell

I got the error. Why it is happening?

```
{#Azar's first shell script
echo "Hi Azar, Welcome to the new world of technology for you"
echo 'default script bash'
echo keep going don't stop always}
```

error:

```
 sh afs.sh
 Hi Azar, Welcome to the new world of technology for you
 default script bash
 afs.sh: 6: afs.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: It's not `echo` syntax, rather it's `bash` preprocessing line before execution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your script fails when you are trying to

```
echo keep going don't stop always
```

The reason is told in the syntax error

```
Unterminated quoted string
```

Because you use `'` in `don't`, Bash shell keeps looking for another `'` that closes your sentence. As it is never found, syntax error is printed.

In this case, you need to use double quotes (" ") like this

```
echo "keep going don't stop always"
```

It is recommended to use quotes when printing out something in general. In double quotes you can use `'` and in single ones `"` if needed.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887366/bash-shell-scripting-error/887373#887368) provided by jiipeezz to this question, you can also use backslash to escape single characters.

`echo keep going don\'t stop always`

For more details [read this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

Comment: Good point, but it is always a good practice to wrap your strings around quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks erroneous. 
I tried the same, but got a command not found error.

```
line 3: $'{#Azars first shell script\necho "Hi Azar, Welcome to the new world of technology for you"\necho default': command not found
```

This script worked without any errors as expected. Escape the quote you have used in "don't" --- "don\'t". This way you do not have to put double quotes around echo statement. But it is a good practice to put them into double quotes.

```
#Azar's first shell script
echo "Hi Azar, Welcome to the new world of technology for you"
echo 'default script bash' 
echo keep going don\'t stop always
```

Output of this script.

```
user@system:~/samplecode$ bash samplescript.sh
Hi Azar, Welcome to the new world of technology for you
default script bash
keep going don't stop always
```

Happy scripting.